# In Binary Serialization(C#) how to skip non serializable fields in a Serializable Object?

Tags: .net, exception

I have a class which is marked with [Serializable] attribute. This class is having many fields of different types. Most of the types being referred by this class have the [Serializable] attribute but a few of them don't have this attribute.

Binary Serialization fails in the above scenario, which is expected.

I have simplified the problem in the above description. In reality I am dealing with a large enterprise application which has complex object hierarchy and deep down into the hierarchy there are a few windows types that cannot be serialized and the Binary Serialization fails. I want a solution for this.

Is there a Custom Binary Serializer available which can skip the fields that can not be serialized?

Note: I am aware of this concept:
[How do you identify the field that is causing binary serialization to fail in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003876/how-do-you-identify-the-field-that-is-causing-binary-serialization-to-fail-in-n)

I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is the solution. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `[NonSerialized]` attribute on a field to skip it entirely once you've identified that it cannot be serialized.

If it's types much further down the hierarchy that you don't have control over that are causing this then what I'd suggest is duplicating the structure of the classes/structs in question sans-unserializable-fields and using something like automapper to deep-copy the values to your new classes, and then serialize the end result.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that can add the [NonSerialized] attribute to a particular field (of the source that is in our control not the .net types) in the hierarchy at runtime and skip serializing further down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample program that helped me solve this problem.

Imagine a object structured like this:
[Sample Object Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSf7P.png)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Root rootObject = new Root();

        FindNonSerializableFields(rootObject, rootObject.GetType().Name, sb);
        string unserializedFields = sb.ToString();
        bool isObjectSerializable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(unserializedFields);
        Console.WriteLine("Is object Serializable? : {0}", isObjectSerializable);
        if (!isObjectSerializable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unserializable Fields:");
            Console.WriteLine(unserializedFields);
        }
    }

    static void FindNonSerializableFields(object obj, string lineage, StringBuilder sb, uint stopAtDepth = 7)
    {
        if (lineage.Count(f => f == '»') >= stopAtDepth)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!IsObjectBinarySerializable(obj))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(lineage);
            var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                object fieldObject = field.GetValue(obj);
                if (fieldObject != null && !Attribute.IsDefined(field, typeof(NonSerializedAttribute)))
                {
                    FindNonSerializableFields(fieldObject, lineage + "»" + fieldObject.GetType().Name, sb);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsObjectBinarySerializable(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(memorystream, obj);
            }
        }
        catch(SerializationException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Root
{
    public L1B1 l1b1 = new L1B1();
    private L1B2 l1b2 = new L1B2();
    protected L1B3 l1b3 = new L1B3();
}

[Serializable]
class L1B1
{
    public L2B1 l2b1 = new L2B1();
}

[Serializable]
class L1B2
{
    private L2B2 l2b2 = new L2B2();
}

[Serializable]
class L1B3
{
    protected L2B3 l2b3 = new L2B3();
}

//[Serializable]
class L2B1
{
    protected Leaf_B1 leaf_b1 = new Leaf_B1();
}

[Serializable]
class L2B2
{
    public Leaf_B2 leaf_b2 = new Leaf_B2();
}

[Serializable]
class L2B3
{
    private Leaf_B3 leaf_b3 = new Leaf_B3();
}

[Serializable]
class Leaf_B1
{
    [NonSerialized]
    private int var1 = 10;
    public string var2 = "string_Leaf_B1";
    public bool var3 = true;
}

[Serializable]
class Leaf_B2
{
    private int var1 = 10;
    [NonSerialized]
    public string var2 = "string_Leaf_B2";
    public bool var3 = true;
}

//[Serializable]
class Leaf_B3
{
    private int var1 = 10;
    public string var2 = "string_Leaf_B3";
    [NonSerialized]
    public bool var3 = true;
}
```

Sample output:

Is object Serializable? : False

Unserializable Fields:

Root

Root»L1B1

Root»L1B1»L2B1

This way I know where exactly the serialization is breaking.

I did not think of performance or any coding standards while writing this sample.
Would be happy to see someone coming up with a better solution.